# code of with only lists just has too many mini errors

Tags: javascript

so the code is not complete it is just a list but the error tells me to add ";" at the end of the sentence but that isn't all of it so I'm just gonna upload the original without any edits and pls just let me why there are so many errors. (don't know if I added the code correctly here)

```
let lists = [
{ 
    id: 1, 
    name: "giorgi", 
    company: [
        {
            id: 1,
            address: "kutaisi"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            address: "wyaltubo"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "giorgi",
    company: [
        {
            id: 1,
            address: "batumi"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            address: "ureki"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "giorgi",
    company: [
        {
            id: 1,
            address: "tbilisi"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            address: "zugdidi"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Your object is incomplete.

Comment: You have missed `}]` at the end of your `lists`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed }] at the end of the code (not sure if thats your problem) try out this

```js
let lists = [
    { 
        id: 1, 
        name: "giorgi", 
        company: [
            {
                id: 1,
                address: "kutaisi"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                address: "wyaltubo"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "giorgi",
        company: [
            {
                id: 1,
                address: "batumi"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                address: "ureki"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "giorgi",
        company: [
            {
                id: 1,
                address: "tbilisi"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                address: "zugdidi"
            }
        ]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object is incomplete, you missed some Brackets, Try this code

```
let lists = [
{ 
    id: 1, 
    name: "giorgi", 
    company: [
        {
            id: 1,
            address: "kutaisi"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            address: "wyaltubo"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "giorgi",
    company: [
        {
            id: 1,
            address: "batumi"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            address: "ureki"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "giorgi",
    company: [
        {
            id: 1,
            address: "tbilisi"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            address: "zugdidi"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score -1):

If that is the hall code you are  missing } ] at the end.
try it out and let us know.